# how to automate a batch script

Tags: batch-file, automation

I would like to run a batch script at 5:00pm every day. How to do that?

Usually QA people automate their test reports every night for regression and BVT test for example. Has anyone any insight into that? How do they automate it. I think they use regular .bat scripts. But they might use some extra tools too.

Comment: I don't think the question deserves a downvote. At least, if the downvote is because the question is offtopic here, I can't see the point. The question can get migrated. Having a low (especially negative) vote count, it may not get proper attention on the other site. Under the circumstances, the downvoting appears highly ungenerous. (Voted to counterbalance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use the scheduler for the OS you're using. Since you mentioned .bat files, I presume you're on some version of Windows. Depending on your windows version, you can use the GUI interface to scheduler, or [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx) or [at](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755618%28WS.10%29.aspx) from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If your Test cases are in an executable file (Ex: testcase.exe) you can use a batch file to call and run those exe file.

```
 $echo off
    :W
    If %time%==17:00:00.00 goto :X
    :X
    testcase.exe /s /f
```

write this batch script to text file save as .bat and run, i hope this will help

Comment: That script is incorrect. But of it had worked, why would you want a batch file looping permanently, slowing the system down?